# Change default keyboard language for Windows PE media

Tags: windows-pe

I have used [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-create-usb-bootable-drive) guide to make a Windows PE flash drive. It works as it should. When I boot a computer into Windows PE a CMD window appears.

The problem is that the keyboard is set to US by default, but I am using a nordic keyboard.

How can I change the default keyboard that loads on the initial CMD window?

I have tried all the following command without any success:

```
Dism /Add-Package /Image:"C:\tmp" /PackagePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\nb-NO\lp.cab"
Dism /Image:"C:\tmp" /Set-SetupUILang:nb-NO
Dism /Image:"C:\tmp" /Set-SKUIntlDefaults:nb-NO
Dism /Image:"C:\tmp" /Set-SysLocale:nb-NO
Dism /Image:"C:\tmp" /Set-UILang:nb-NO
Dism /Image:"C:\tmp" /Set-UILangFallBack:nb-NO
Dism /Image:"C:\tmp" /Set-UserLocale:nb-NO
Dism /Image:"C:\tmp" /Set-InputLocale:nb-NO
Dism /Image:"C:\tmp" /Set-AllIntl:nb-NO
```

If I investigate I can see that Norwegian keybobard is in fact installed. That is `0414:00000414`. So that is kind of weird.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools>Dism /online /Get-Intl

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.17763.1

Image Version: 10.0.17763.437

Reporting online international settings.

Default system UI language : en-US
System locale : nb-NO
Default time zone : W. Europe Standard Time
Active keyboard(s) : 0409:00000414, 0414:00000414
Keyboard layered driver : PC/AT Enhanced Keyboard (101/102-Key)

Installed language(s): en-US
  Type : Fully localized language.
```

Do I really have to type `wpeutil SetKeyboardLayout 0409:00000414` each time I load Windows PE? Is there no other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [input profiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-input-locales-for-windows-language-packs) are made up of a *language identifier* and a *keyboard identifier*.

For example: `0409:00000414`

A language identifier is a standard international numeric abbreviation for the language in a country or geographical region. For example `0409` is the hexadecimal identifier of the language United States (US) and `00000414` is the hexadecimal identifier of the keyboard "Norway/Norwegian".

Change

```
Dism /Image:"C:\tmp" /Set-InputLocale:nb-NO
```

to

```
Dism /Image:"C:\tmp" /Set-InputLocale:0409:00000414
```

and you will get Nowegian keyboard input at the initial CMD screen once Windows PE has loaded.

[image]

Not really sure why `nb-NO` does not work. The [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-languages-and-international-servicing-command-line-options) says you can use it...

Answer (score 1):

You can setup your keyboard as follows:

- In the customized Windows PE image, go to `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32`
- Edit the file `Startnet.cmd` containing the startup script
- Add the command:

  ```
  wpeutil setkeyboardlayout 0414:00000414
  ```

More info and keyboard layouts in the article
[Set Keyboard Layout in MDT and SCCM Task Sequence](https://www.andersrodland.com/set-keyboard-layout-mdt-sccm-task-sequence/), where I have found listed these
possible Norwegian keyboard layouts:

[image]

Comment: This seems to kind of work, but you still need to open a new instance of CMD with `start CMD` after Startnet.cmd have launched so it's not really a solution, more like a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Permanently change the keyboard layout in WinPE:

1. Mount the boot.wim image:

> dism /mount-image /imagefile:"c:\windowspe\media\sources\boot.wim"
> /index:1 /mountdir:"c:\windowsPE\mount"

2. Check the keyboard settings with the command below (active keyboards):

> dism /image:"c:\windowsPE\mount" /get-intl

**NOTE: Keep in mind that if you use the /online parameter instead of the /image parameter, you get the keyboard of your running windows installation instead of the one installed in the winpe image!!**

3. If the keyboard is not correct, you can change it with the command below:

> dism /image:"c:\windowsPE\mount" /set-inputlocale:0813:00000813

**NOTE: The inputlocale I have used above, is for the belgian period keyboard. Please change it to the value for your keyboard**

4. Unmount the image and commit the changes:

> dism /unmount-image /mountdir:"c:\windowsPE\mount" /commit

5. Create an iso file of the changed image

> makewinpemedia /iso c:\windowsPE C:\windowspe.iso

6. You can now test the iso by creating a virtual machine in hyper-V, and point to the iso you just created. If it boots, and works correct, you can create a bootable usb with the command below: (change D: to the drive letter of your usb device)

> makewinpemedia /ufd c:\windowsPE D: